# What does this code mean exactly?

Tags: java, try-catch, parseint

I am just not sure exactly what this section of code means.

```
try {
    startGame(Integer.parseInt(clickedButton.getLabel()));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Comment: What about it is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt()` takes in a `String` and returns an `int`. So the label of that button must be String that holds a numeric value. The method `startGame` must take in an `int` to know which game to start. If the label is **NOT** a number, it will go into the `catch` block by throwing a `NumberFormatException`.

The `catch` part is `log4j` that will output to either a log file and/or console (depends on configuation) with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If Integer.parseInt() can not convert what ever string that is in clickedButton's Label then it will throw an error.

The error will then get catched by the try catch and create a log message with a level of severe with the stack trace that had happened.

It threw an exception because the clickedButton's Label is not a number.

Comment: `it will throw an ...` "exception" ;).

Comment: @Tom Ya beat me to it :)
It will not just send, but log a message, depending on the developers configuration.

Comment: @Stultuske, I used create rather than send.